# Calculate and output numerical values from input fields

Tags: ember.js

I want to multiply two input fields and display the result in real time.

Where do I put the calculation and how do I output the result?

```
<div>
  <label>Number of ice creams:</label>
  {{input type="text" value=numberOne}}
</div>
<div>
  <label>The price for an ice cream:</label>
  {{input type="text" value=numberTwo}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put you calculations in the controller. The total value should be a computed property, so that it will update automatically when the dependent values changes.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  numberOne: 5,
  numberTwo: 10,
  total: function() {
    return this.get('numberOne') * this.get('numberTwo');
  }.property('numberOne', 'numberTwo')
});
```

[Here is a working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fujid/1/edit)